# How to use the progress bar of google closure tools effectively?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-library

I would like to show the progress bar using google closure library
during heavy calculation in JavaScript. A sample code is below.

```
// An essential code which is not working well
var pb = new goog.ui.ProgressBar;

for (i = 0; i < 100; i += 1) {
   // Some costly process here
   pb.setValue(i);
};
```

I know JavaScript is fully single thread model. So a snippet above
is not working as I expected.
Does anyone know an effective approach to use the closure progress bar in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The most common approach is to break down your costly process into small chunks, and update your progress bar on each iteration. That is unless you want to consider using [web workers](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-workers/current-work/), but these are only supported in a few modern browsers.

On a separate note, don't forget to declare the `i` variable, because otherwise it will become an implied global variable.